# Why does online retro game emulation run extremely poorly on Microsoft Edge on my Desktop PC?

Tags: cpu, performance, browser, terminator, old-hardware

OS Name: Microsoft Windows 10 Pro

Processor: Intel(R) Core™ i7-10700T CPU @ 2.00GHz, 1992 Mhz, 8 Core(s), 16 Logical Processor(s)

RAM: 16.0 GB

Version: 22H2

I want to play the Sega CD version of The Terminator which is available to play online on a bunch of different websites but the problem is that the emulation of the game itself regardless of the website, runs extremely poorly when using Microsoft Edge (and Firefox as well).

I get very low frame rates with choppy audio.  https://www.playretrogames.com/4623-the-terminator

but the strange thing is if I use Brave then the game runs absolutely perfect at a solid 60 FPS.  How do I get the game to perform like it does on Brave but with using Microsoft Edge instead?

I've tried using private mode on Edge (with all add-ons disabled) but that didn't help.

I've tried playing with the **Use graphics acceleration when available** & **Improve your PC gaming experience with efficiency mode** settings but that didn't help either.

The game emulation of the Sega CD version of The Terminator is extremely slow and laggy with audio that keeps breaking up.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: As you state, I've confirmed that Brave has a speed advantage here. On a faster machine, I've also confirmed there is *less* stuttering in Firefox, bu still some, even in Safe mode. However, Brave Browser might *not* be Chrome based, while Firefox and Edge are. So you really have answered you own question -- use non-Chrome *Brave*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Firefox is not Chrome/Chromium based unlike pretty much everything else available nowadays is (Chromium based), including Chrome itself and Edge. That's not the difference here.

Comment: Yes DrMoishe Pippik you are correct when you say there is less stuttering when attempting to play the game in Firefox vs when attempting to play the game in Edge, but the low frame rate and choppy audio still makes the game fairly unplayable on Firefox too. 

Firefox is non-Chromium, Brave & Edge are Chromium which make things confusing given that the game runs at its best on Brave and at it's worst on Edge.

Comment: Brave is Chromium based. Firefox is not. I believe Firefox and Safari are the only two major browsers that are not Chromium based these days.

Comment: Microsoft has been busy adding lots of features to Edge. I don't know how well published all the changes are, but there do seem to be a LOT of bells and whistles being added, and I'm guessing that it may be impossible to know for CERTAIN what is causing such issues. You could try using the Inspector to figure out what's going on possibly, at least seeing what in the site itself is hanging up, which may give clues to what in the browser is causing the issues.